# MinGW make.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running

Tags: makefile, mingw

I am currently running a 64 bit version of Windows 11 in the Developer Channel, and when attempting to build a Makefile, I continue to run into this issue. I've attempted to look this up online, but no information was of use. Is MinGW make.exe just incompatible with Windows 11, and is there a method to fix this? I am very much a beginner to C++ and Makefiles, and my experience is lacking.

Comment: Why not use Visual Studio Community?

Comment: Which MinGW (or MinGW-w64) exactly are you using?
Can you try with the standalone MinGW-w64 from https://winlibs.com/ ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling MinGW-w64 into a different directory (one without a space), my issue was resolved, and MinGW-make.exe now works.